# Cant import folly/facebook c++ lib

Tags: c++, facebook, folly

I am currently trying to use the atomic_hashmaps from [folly/facebook](https://github.com/facebook/folly) c++ library, but after the folly installation, if I simply require the lib like

```
#include <folly/AtomicHashMap.h>
```

The g++ compiler throws the following exception:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/folly/ThreadLocal.h:40:0,
         from /usr/local/include/folly/ThreadCachedInt.h:31,
         from /usr/local/include/folly/AtomicHashArray.h:41,
         from /usr/local/include/folly/AtomicHashMap.h:93,
         from cartesian_zero.cpp:11:
/usr/local/include/folly/Portability.h:203:20: fatal error: __config: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I am compiling my C++ code with:

```
g++-5.1.0 -std=c++11 -o3 -lhiredis -fopenmp cartesian_zero.cpp
```

is it a folly's issue or my fault?

Comment: At first, I thought you were missing the -I option to find includes.  But since you can file the folly headers, that's not the case.  It looks like an install/config issue.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: When you did the install/build, what compiler did it use?  I'm asking because you use a specific compiler (g++-5.1.0).  If the install/build doesn't know about that specific compiler, it may use the default (e.g. /usr/bin/g++ if you're on Linux).

Comment: I just checked the Makefile, and it indeed used the default osx c compiler. I just changed all g++ variables in Makefile to g++-5.1.0. Let's see if it does the trick